# what is the argument i should pass here

Tags: android, exoplayer

i am working with exoplayer and now i am trying to downloading audio.i have done with creating download manager and more now i am getting error in passing argument see in picture...

[image]

here is the code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exoplayer);

        thumb = findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        head = findViewById(R.id.head);

        String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
         url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");


        head.setText(title);
        Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(image).into(thumb);

        //download
        head.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ProgressiveDownloadAction progressiveDownloadAction = new ProgressiveDownloadAction(url,false,null, null);//here where i am getting error

                DownloadService.startWithAction(exoplayer.this, AudioDownloadService.class, null,false);
            }
        });


        initializeplayer();
    }

    public void initializeplayer(){

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.exo);
        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

        DataSource.Factory datasourcefactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "appname"));

       CacheDataSourceFactory cacheDataSourceFactory =  new CacheDataSourceFactory(DownloadUtil.getCache(this),datasourcefactory);

        ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource();//

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)//it was datasourcefactory
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));

        concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource);//

        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }
```

now what argument needed there. help me if anyone can.

EDIT:
after passing Uri.parse(url) getting this error...

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadAction.toByteArray()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadService.buildAddActionIntent(DownloadService.java:173)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadService.startWithAction(DownloadService.java:190)
        at com.example.project.exoplayer$1.onClick(exoplayer.java:60)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:442)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Answer (score 0):

In your ProgressiveDownloadAction constructor, use `Uri.parse(url)` instead of url

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.DownloadAction.toByteArray()' on a null object reference.   getting this error after passing Uri.parse(url)

Comment: this means that your `url` variable is null. Make sure you pass it correclty to your activity

Comment: Url variable has value which i pass in exoplayer to stream audio. I can stream audio perfectly but i want to download that audio file.

Comment: that NullPointerException means that the url is actually null. Please double check it (e.g. set a breakpoint in Android Studio)